# c++11, why does this unordered_map defined for vector <int> not work?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create an `unordered_map<vector<int>, int>`. I know that I need to have my own hash function, so I tried to build one. I am capable of creating it and compiling it fine, but I get compilation errors when I try to access it.

Here is the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class mhash {
public:
  std::size_t operator()(std::vector<int> const& vec) const {
    std::size_t seed = vec.size();
    for(auto& i : vec) {
     seed ^= i + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
     }
  return seed;
    }
};

map <vector <int>,int, mhash> M;

int main(){
    vector <int> V;
    M[V]=5;
    cout << M[V];
}
```

I am compiling using `g++ -std=c++11`.

If I only declare the `unordered_map` it compiles fine, but when I try to use it I get the following errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/map:61:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/stdc++.h:80,
                 from exp.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_map.h: In instantiation of ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::vector<int>; _Tp = int; _Compare = mhash; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::vector<int>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::vector<int>]’:
exp.cpp:19:5:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_map.h:481:32: error: no match for call to ‘(std::map<std::vector<int>, int, mhash>::key_compare {aka mhash}) (const key_type&, const std::vector<int>&)’
  if (__i == end() || key_comp()(__k, (*__i).first))
                                ^
exp.cpp:6:15: note: candidate: std::size_t mhash::operator()(const std::vector<int>&) const
   std::size_t operator()(std::vector<int> const& vec) const {
               ^
exp.cpp:6:15: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/map:60:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/stdc++.h:80,
                 from exp.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h: In instantiation of ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_lower_bound(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type, std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type, const _Key&) [with _Key = std::vector<int>; _Val = std::pair<const std::vector<int>, int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::vector<int>, int> >; _Compare = mhash; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::vector<int>, int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::vector<int>, int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<const std::vector<int>, int> >*]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h:1091:30:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::lower_bound(const key_type&) [with _Key = std::vector<int>; _Val = std::pair<const std::vector<int>, int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::vector<int>, int> >; _Compare = mhash; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::vector<int>, int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::vector<int>, int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::vector<int>]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_map.h:916:36:   required from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::lower_bound(const key_type&) [with _Key = std::vector<int>; _Tp = int; _Compare = mhash; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::vector<int>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::vector<int>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::vector<int>]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_map.h:479:28:   required from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::vector<int>; _Tp = int; _Compare = mhash; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::vector<int>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::vector<int>]’
exp.cpp:19:5:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h:1628:6: error: no match for call to ‘(mhash) (const std::vector<int>&, const std::vector<int>&)’
  if (!_M_impl._M_key_compare(_S_key(__x), __k))
      ^
exp.cpp:6:15: note: candidate: std::size_t mhash::operator()(const std::vector<int>&) const
   std::size_t operator()(std::vector<int> const& vec) const {
               ^
exp.cpp:6:15: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Comment: How are you trying to use it and what errors do you get?

Comment: that is the exact use I am trying to give it. The errors I get are simply from the above code, Ill add the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you instantiated a `std::map`, not an `std::unordered_map`.

Normal maps don't take hash functions.

Presumably this is just a typo.

By the way, [avoid `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648).

Comment: My programming experience is limited to contests, thats why I use the include bits thing.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote map, not unordered_map.

But... if you want a **map**:
The third template argument for a **map** is not a hash, but a comparator.
*bool operator()(a, b)*